# E: Unable to locate package code visual studio code

Tags: ubuntu, vscode

como andan? Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con mi vps de hostinger, estoy intentando abrir visual studio code en mi vps con el siguiente comando:

```
code .
```

Pero al ejecutarlo, no me deja abrirlo ya que me arroja el siguiente error:

```
-bash: code: command not found
```

Por lo tanto procedo a querer instalar visual studio code con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt install code
```

y me arroja lo siguiente:

```
E: Unable to locate package code
```

Estoy trabajando con Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve un problema similar con paquetes de instalación, es porque ese paquete no existe.
Para instalar ***vs code*** prueba con este comando para instalarlo desde un paquete snap.

```
sudo snap install --classic code
```